# TypeORM: many-to-one relation targeting different entity types

Tags: typescript, sqlite, typeorm

I'm trying to model the following situation in TypeORM:

```
[ItemContainer]-(0..1)---(0..n)-[ContainableItem]-(0..n)---(0..1)-[ItemLocation]
```

Or in words: A `ContainableItem` can be in either an `ItemContainer` or at an `ItemLocation`. In practice it won't be able to appear in both at the same time, but this is not important for the problem at hand. Additionally, I'd like to point out that there is no overlap between `ItemContainer` and `ItemLocation`, they are completely different entities.

I tried modelling this situation by putting a `one-to-many` on both `ItemContainer` and `ItemLocation` pointing to `ContainableItem`.

But I'm having difficulties modelling the `many-to-one` relation from the point of view of the `ContainableItem`. How can I tell TypeORM that `ContainableItem.parent` points to either an `ItemContainer` or an `ItemLocation`?

**ContainableItem Schema (snippet)**

```js
{
  ...
  relations: {
    parent: {
      type: 'many-to-one',
      target: ItemContainer.name || ItemLocation.name,
      inverseSide: nameof<ItemContainer |ItemLocation >((cl) => cl.items),
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you have to create 2 columns that can be nullable for both ItemContainer and ItemLocation. then if item available in  location you can put location id and leave item container null or if item in itemcontainer then you can put container id for there and leave null in  item location. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was how I initially had modelled it. I was trying to avoid having multiple columns, but it may be the most straightforward implementation